# Failed audit on First Post question even though I made a good comment on it

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I got the following question while reviewing First Posts:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/24247042

I didn't understand what the author of the question meant by "pair" so I wrote a comment and asked about clarification. This made me fail the audit.

I dispute that since it turned out that the actual question received the same comment and that comment received 6 votes, so clearly my action on this First Post was a good one.

This is the first Audit I failed of many which is a bit annoying. Can some admin please undo the classification of this being a failed audit, and also prevent this from showing up for others?

Comment: *"Can some admin please undo the classification of this being a failed audit"* I don't think that's possible. *"and also prevent this from showing up for others"* That's not necessary. The problem isn't the audit, the problem is that a comment fails the audit. That has been discussed here already, I wonder if that works as a dupe? [Review audit failed after just clicking "add comment"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260803)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate because 1. I could write and submit my comment before the audit failed, and 2. that is an audit for an answer, in my case it is for a question.

Comment: Yep, I would have asked the same question myself. In fact, I'm not totally sure this is clear *now* - we have to infer what OP means by a pair by the output expected. You could totally break the array into uneven pairs `10,10`, `10,10`, `20,20`, `20,30` - 4 pairs of numbers. Or you can have pairs that sum up to the same number. Or any other criteria, it doesn't specify pairs of *identical elements*.

Comment: Question or answer doesn't matter and if you fail before or after you wrote a comment doesn't matter either for this question to qualify as a dupe. The issue here is the incorrect audit handling when writing a comment. But it also doesn't look like that this will be changed. A Stack Exchange employee already wrote there and didn't seem to understand the problem (although that was 5 years ago).

Comment: This is also about reporting this particular Audit as described here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work So trying to find a duplicate doesn’t really make sense. Unless this particular Audit turns out to have been reported before.

Comment: Like I said, this audit is not at fault.

Comment: If you fail an Audit even though you took good action, it is a bad Audit.

Comment: If you ended up with a review ban over this audit update your question; you might be able to get it rescinded by a moderator; and if one thinks the question's unclear (I thought the intent was obvious since there was only 1 reasonable way to get 3) might remove it from being used as an audit in the future.  The pass/fail behavior of the review queue isn't going to be changed.  Unfortunately all you can do is to learn what actions count as a pass/fail for audits and open the question in a separate tab to check if it is one so you don't fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't spend much time in the First Posts queue so I'm not intimately familiar with the audit process there, but I'll try to address as much of your question as I can.

> I didn't understand what the author of the question meant by "pair" so I wrote a comment and asked about clarification. This made me fail the audit.

For what it's worth, I agree with you -- the asker hasn't made it clear at all even with a followup comment. I have asked an additional clarification request for OP, though since it has multiple answers already, I'm not sure if OP is still paying attention to the question. Time will tell!

> This is the first Audit I failed of many which is a bit annoying.

That's great that this is the first time you've failed an audit. You will fail many more as you continue reviewing, and hopefully they'll only be because of bad audits (of which there are *many*).

> Can some admin please undo the classification of this being a failed audit

Unfortunately, elected moderators don't have the ability to revert a failed audit for a reviewer. Luckily, one failed audit isn't that big a deal, especially if it is your first one. Enough time between failed audits, or enough passed audits between failed audits, and you will never experience a review ban. There's also no score board where people will see any audit failures blasted into the public space (though they can see the details if they find the specific review item in the review queue history), so don't worry about negative press.

> and also prevent this from showing up for others?

I don't recall the exact qualifying criteria for audit items (or if they vary from queue to queue) but it's unlikely this one can be removed from the 'audit pool' short of overwhelming intervention from the community (or intervention from an employee, also unlikely).

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. Once I saw the full question with comments included I actually understood what a pair was. But during the audit you don’t see any comments on the question. Either way, OP actually clarified this even more now after your question which is good I guess. (I will wait some more days before marking an answer as accepted.)